# FFMPEG video conversion for pygame

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I am currently making a program on python (3) using the pygame module. One of the things I need it to do is to play a video which is currently in AVI format.

From what I managed to understand from the `pygame.movie` documentation I have to use FFMPEG and not another program to convert the video to an MPEG (I tried it with NCH Prism and the result was quite memorable).

I managed to convert my file to an MPG using the sample command found in the `pygame.movie` documentation (`ffmpeg -i <infile> -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec libmp3lame -intra <outfile.mpg>`) but the video quality dropped very much. I tried looking at different cites but they never actually had a working example...

Is there a way to keep the current video quality? I don't really care about the file size...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There will be some loss of quality, that's unavoidable, but you can try forcing a high bitrate and then stepping it down while quality remains acceptable. Start with something like

`ffmpeg -i infile -vcodec mpeg1video -b:v 8192k -acodec libmp3lame -intra outfile.mpg`

and work from there